# Best way to have a debugger class in OOP?

Tags: php, oop, debugging

I'm wondering what's the best way to make a class with the usual debug code (logs, prints, profiles, etc).

I don't like how it reads when I have to instantiate a new debug object each time I want to log something. A global object doesn't look better.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Umm, what are you talking about? :) Are you talking about a framework or what?

Comment: Install xdebug and use a code profiler?

Comment: No, I used debug as an example of a set of tools used across all other classes. In this case is a small class that have methods like log()

Answer (score 2):

Use [static methods.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)  Static methods do not require instantiation of an object to execute them.

Comment: Yes, thought about that... but you'll loose the ability to use non-static properties (to configure the debugger, etc)

Comment: @Rabine: Those static (or alternatively just global) functions can refer to an object instance they know of.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using static methods, you can avoid outputting PHP parse errors and such using the [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and [set_exception_handler()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) functions, and defining a function (for each one) written in PHP to handle those errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Singleton pattern. in singleton pattern, instantiation is automatically restricted to once. that is, one class has one and only one instance.
please visit the following link:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php